# Css of override default video play button on mobile devices

Tags: css, html, mobile, video, html5-video

In html5 video player, how can i use css to override or float an image with clickable link in front of default video play button on mobile devices like iPhone and etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use media queries to target the screen width appropriate for the devices you want to see the new button.  Apply css in that media query of `display: none;` for the **DEFAULT** button.  Make completely separate HTML for the new button, and make it `display: block;` for the new button under your new media query.

Then for media query for screens larger than your mobile size inverse the above, make the default button `display: block;` and the new one `display: none;`

Comment: what is the css for the default button? .default_button { display: none} It must be something specific.

Comment: @Jackson_Sandland , if you have an issue, make a new question m8.  IDK the default CSS for the video player, but you can probably figure it out with inspect element.